# ¿Cómo crear un filtro a una matriz json por fechas?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Tengo esta matriz json el cual tiene algunos datos y devuelve los valores a una tabla html, estoy programando con php pero ahora tengo un pequeño inconveniente para filtrar los datos por fecha estoy comenzando a aprender json y me quedo corto

```php
<?php
    $jsonobj = '{
        "codigo": "00",
        "descripcion": "Consulta exitosa",
        "movimientos": [
        {
            "comercio_desc": "ATIPICO RIVERA",
            "fch_com": "06/01/21",
            "importe": "10000",
            "mov_tp": "D",
            "referencia_nro": "100530994259",
            "tarjeta": "6274311750000090"
        },
        {
            "comercio_desc": "COMERCIAL 1",
            "fch_com": "06/01/21",
            "importe": "350000",
            "mov_tp": "D",
            "referencia_nro": "100530994259",
            "tarjeta": "6274311750000090"
        },
        {
            "comercio_desc": "COMERCIAL 2",
            "fch_com": "06/01/21",
            "importe": "350000",
            "mov_tp": "D",
            "referencia_nro": "100530994259",
            "tarjeta": "6274311750000090"
        }
        ]
    }';
 $decodedJson = json_decode($jsonobj, true);
?>
```

En esta tabla se muestran los valores de la matriz funciona con un bucle el cual puede leer las filas, estoy utilizando json_decode para devolver los valores a un tipo php y html y ahora tengo un inconveniente al filtrar los datos por fecha lo he he intentado de varias formas sin resultado, ¿alguien podría ayudarme por favor?

```html
<table id="tblUsuarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-td-valign-middle" cellspacing="0" width="100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="hidden-sm text-center">Codigo</th>
          <th class="hidden-sm text-center">descripcion</th>
          <th class="hidden-sm text-center">comercio_desc</th>
          <th class="hidden-sm text-center">fch_com</th>
          <th class="hidden-sm text-center">importe</th>
          <th class="hidden-sm text-center">mov_tp</th>
          <th class="hidden-sm text-center">referencia_nro</th>
          <th class="hidden-sm text-center">tarjeta</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <?php  for ($i=0; $i <count($decodedJson["movimientos"]); $i++) {   
     ?>
      <tbody>


        <tr>
          <td class="text-nowrap text-inverse text-center">
            <?php echo $decodedJson["codigo"]; ?> </td>
          <td class="text-nowrap text-inverse text-center">
            <?php echo $decodedJson["descripcion"]; ?>
          </td>
          <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center">
            <?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][$i]["comercio_desc"]; ?> </td>
          <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center">
            <?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][$i]["fch_com"]; ?> </td>
          <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center">
            <?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][$i]["importe"]; ?> </td>
          <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center">
            <?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][$i]["mov_tp"]; ?>
          </td>
          <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center">
            <?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][$i]["referencia_nro"]; ?>
          </td>
          <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center">
            <?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][$i]["tarjeta"]; ?> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <?php
    }
                                            
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: A partir de $decodedJson["movimientos"][$i]["fch_com"] y utilizando https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php puedes intentarlo

Comment: también puedes re ordenar el array de movimientos ocupando la función usort de php https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php